# Estimating the error bounds for a derivative chart of data

Tags: regression, measurement-error, error-propagation

I have collected position (S) versus time (t) data.  A typical result is shown in the following chart:

[image]

As can be seen all three regression models provide excellent fits to the mean values of the data points and on this plot are indistinguishable.  The experimental errors in the measurement of S are from left to right 0%, 11%, 24%, 20%, 12% and 17%. These percent error measurements are based on the standard deviations of five readings divided by the mean.  Now at any time the instantaneous velocity is equal to the derivative of the three regression models at that time.  That yields a chart something like this.

[image]

The experiments measured S as in the first figure but could also directly measure velocities at the ends of the region of interest (identified as the black triangles).  However, velocities for data points in between could not be directly measured, but instead are estimated from the derivatives of the regression models. Except for the end points, the interior points for all three models are close enough to be considered identical.

If I wanted to show how the error in the S vs t plot impacts the v vs. t plot, I'm not sure how to do this. Do I just show an upper and lower bound where, for example, the second value from the left (first value is at t = 0) on the v vs t chart would be 2.43 $\pm$11% (so a range of 2.16 to 2.7), the third value would be 2.235 $\pm$24% so a range of 1.7 to 2.77 and so on?? If I do that, the plot looks something like this where the green dots represent the upper bound and the orange dots the lower bound:

[image]

Or since I used equations to get the velocities, maybe I need to apply the errors in the S vs t data to each equation and then recalculate the velocities from each equation, which will probably be tedious.  Or perhaps there is another way that I should do this.  A published reference states that errors tend to be magnified when taking derivatives.

FIRST EDIT BY OP:

I decided to rerun the velocities calculated from each of the regression models with S varying from the mean by the stated error percentages listed above. A chart that I posted previously where I just applied the error from the S vs. t curve to the v vs. t curve, doesn't really make sense since the velocities are calculated from the derivative of each of the regression model equations.  Here is what the results for each regression look like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's interesting how the biggest deviations for the velocity vs time chart are near t = 0, where on the S vs t chart there was hardly any error. As time increases the lower bound, mean, and upper bound values converge for the hyperbolic and exponential association and mostly for the rational model as well.

This method seems like the correct way to assess how the error in the experimental values of the displacements (S) propagate through to the derivatives of the regressions when calculating v.  Unless someone has some issues or concerns, I'm going to go forward with this method for reporting the error.

Editor:  Please make the added charts smaller similar to the charts originally posted.

Comment: How are you estimating the curves? Non-linear least squares?